# Trivy report to sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube-scan, trivy

Is there a way to integrate trivy to sonarqube. I'm building a docker image from jenkins pipeline and then do the trivy scan. Now I want to get that image scan result from trivy in jenkins to the sonarqube. Is it possible to do it?